# SpriteKit + iOS8. Does SpriteKit support "baking" rendered results?

Tags: sprite-kit, ios8

I am implementing a paint program in SpriteKit and I am super impressed by the simplicity of implementation SprikeKit enables. **Very** cool indeed!

Each brush stroke is implemented as a `SKSpriteNode` with attached `SKShader`. Everything works as I expect.

Issue: Currently I am steadily growing the `SKScene` graph as brush strokes are appended. This is not a scalable solution as resource consumption mushrooms and framerate slows to a crawl. So, what I want to do "bake" the `SKScene` graph after brush stroke is painted.

I tried setting `myScene.shouldRasterize = YES` on my `SKScene` instance but it appeared to have no effect. How do I "bake" rendering results in SpriteKit? Do I have to roll my own?

Thanks,
Doug

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The only was I can think of to do this is to call [`textureFromNode`](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/documentation/SpriteKit/Reference/SKView/index.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/SKView/textureFromNode:) on your `SKView` passing in the `SKNode` that you want to "bake". Then take that texture, apply it to a `SKSpriteNode`, and remove the `SKNode`(s) that you just "baked" in to the texture.

Comment: Yep. That is the approach I am leaning to. Cheers, Mike.

Answer (score 1):

Wanted to add a comment but reputation won't allow me. Just would like to add that you can rasterize group of sprites by using `SKEffectNode`. Just add any sprite to this node then use the same `shouldRasterize` property. You can even apply CoreImage filters to it such as Gaussian Blurs.

The downside is obviously performance when created the rasterized node.

Comment: Thanks Willhem. I went with textureFromNode and the results are exactly what I want. SpriteKit is ridiculously productive. For most 2D I used to use OpenGL/GLSL I can use SpriteKit/GLSL.